# CSS stop span from extending parent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

We are using the twitter bootstrap thumbnails.

We are adding a description underneath the same as in the bootstrap documentation.
The difference is that we don't have a size specified (the documentation uses `.span4`) on our thumbnails, instead the content sizes them.

This works great, except we want one difference, we don't want a long caption to extend the thumbnail, instead we want the extra caption length to be be hidden.

This would be easy if we were using fixed width's but since we are not I have no idea how to do this;

Here is a jsfiddle playground: http://jsfiddle.net/BbCQK/

I thought maybe I could just do:

```
.caption {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipses;
}
```

But that doesn't work, it just stretches the container anyway, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it :)

Absolute positioning to the rescue: http://jsfiddle.net/BbCQK/4/

```
a.thumbnail {
    padding - bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}.thumbnail.caption {
    overflow: hidden;
    white - space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    text - overflow: ellipsis;
}
```